# Possible states of an electronic configuration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin, orbitals

I am having a problem defining all possible states for the electron configuration for more than two electrons in the same orbital.

Let's suppose that we have the following electronic configuration:
$$
[...]np^3
$$
Then I have the following possible total orbital angular momentum and total spin momentum values:
$$
\hat{L}=\sum \hat{l_i}
\\
\hat{S}=\sum \hat{s_i}
\\
L \in \{0,1,2,3\}
\\
S \in \{1/2,3/2\}
$$
So I can have many possible Term Symbols $n^{2S+1}L_{J}$.

The problem is that not all of the states are possible due to Pauli's Exclusion Principle (antisymmetry of the wave function).

But in order to find that, the only way I know would be to write all possible $|L,M>$ states, see if they are antisymmetric or symmetric, and then combine them with the possible spin states that make them antisymmetric in total.

My question is then: is it possible to determine the symmetry of the eigenfunctions of the operator $\hat{L}$ just by the eigenvalue or by any other way that doesn't imply writing all possible $|L,M>$ states?